# How to multiply a function by an integer?

Tags: python, function, multiplication

So I need to calculate how much money a user spends monthly then use that number to calculate how much they spend yearly. To do that I wanted to multiply their monthly expenses with 12 to get their yearly expenses, but I keep arriving at the same error where I cannot multiply an int and a function with the operator "*"

```
def loan_payment():
    loan = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on loan payments:"))
    return loan
def insurance_cost():
    insurance = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on insurance:"))
    return insurance
def gas_cost():
    gas = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on gas:"))
    return gas
def maitanence_cost():
    maitanence = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on maintanence:"))
    return maitanence
def monthly_cost():
    monthly_expenses = float(loan + insurance + gas + maintanence)
    return float(monthly_expenses)
    print("You expend $"+format(monthly_cost, '.2f')+"in a month.")
def yearly_cost():
    yearly_expenses = 12 * monthly_cost
    return yearly_expenses
    print("At your current monthly expenses, in a year you will have paid $"+format(yearly_cost, '.2f')+".")
def main():
    loan_payment()
    insurance_cost()
    gas_cost()
    maitanence_cost()
    monthly_cost
    yearly_cost()
main()
```

Comment: should `12 * monthly_cost` be `12 * monthly_cost()`?

Comment: You don't multiply functions by integers. You multiply the result of function calls by integers, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're learning how to use functions.

```
def loan_payment():
    loan = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on loan payments:"))
    return loan
def insurance_cost():
    insurance = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on insurance:"))
    return insurance
def gas_cost():
    gas = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on gas:"))
    return gas
def maitanence_cost():
    maitanence = float(input("Please enter how much you expend monthly on maintanence:"))
    return maitanence
def monthly_cost(loan, insurance, gas, maitanence):
    monthly_expenses = float(loan + insurance + gas + maitanence)

    print("You expend $"+format(monthly_expenses, '.2f')+"in a month.")
    return float(monthly_expenses)
def yearly_cost(monthly_cost):
    yearly_expenses = 12 * monthly_cost

    print("At your current monthly expenses, in a year you will have paid $".format(yearly_expenses, '.2f') + ".")
    return yearly_expenses

loan = loan_payment()
insurance = insurance_cost()
gas = gas_cost()
maitanence = maitanence_cost()

monthly_cost = monthly_cost(loan, insurance, gas, maitanence)

yearly_cost(monthly_cost)
```

Is what you want.

Whatever you're returning using the `return` statement, I'm assigning it to a variable. So once I've collected them, I can pass them in the `monthly_cost()` function which collects the 4 variables.

Also more, `return` only if you want to exit from the function. The `print` statement will not be executed if you `return` before it reaches the `print` statement. I hope all of this makes sense. W

Understand how `return` works!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parenthesis to call the function:

```
yearly_expenses = 12 * monthly_cost()
```

Then you have unreachable code: The last line `print...` cannot be reached.

```
def monthly_cost():
    monthly_expenses = float(loan + insurance + gas + maintanence)
    return float(monthly_expenses)
    print("You expend $"+format(monthly_cost, '.2f')+"in a month.")
```